# How to set/show nameservers as the domain name is

Tags: nameserver

Assume, www.superexample.com is my domain name and ns1.somehosting.com is my nameserver. What I want is to show/set my **nameservers** as **superexample.com** or **ns1.superexample.com**. How? Please,don't say it's not possible, I've seen it on whois of several websites.

Answer (score 2):

**For something to be identified as a nameserver it must be one.** This means that the server at superexample.com must be running both an HTTP server (HTTPD) and a DNS server (BIND) with a publicly reachable address and port..

You can see this with a lot of hosting sites, they run their own DNS servers and set themselves as the nameserver. Here is the record for [Blue Host](http://reports.internic.net/cgi/whois?whois_nic=bluehost.com&type=domain). On the other hand, as one of their customers, my site on Blue Host shows them as my DNS.

Comment: Can you just clarify... "You **can this** with a lot of hosting sites" - "can do" or "can't do"?

Comment: Oops! Sorry the missing word remained in my head :) *you can see this with*

Answer (score 2):

It needs a couple of things to be done:

1. Find out IP Address, `ns1.somehosting.com` is pointing to.
2. Create a Child Name Server say `ns1.superexample.com` pointing to the same IP Address.
3. Modify NS of `superexample.com` to `ns1.superexample.com`

Some, DNS does not allow single NS entry, in that case find two IP addresses being pointed by `ns1.somehosting.com` and `ns2.somehosting.com`; And create two Child Name Servers say:

```
ns1.superexample.com and ns2.superexample.com
```

You need to login domain management panel provided at the time you register your domains.

**EDIT**:
This answer is based on:

1. http://manage.resellerclub.com/kb/servlet/KBServlet/faq456.html
2. http://manage.resellerclub.com/kb/servlet/KBServlet/faq455.html

Answer (score 0):

Because previous answers are just bad:

1. Read **good books** and **use conventional terms**

www.superexample.com is **NOT domain**, it's **FQDN** of **host in your domain**, you domain is superexample.com with host in in www, and authoritative DNS-server of your domain is ns1.somehosting.com

If for registered and active domain you want to change FQDN of authoritative DNS-server and use DNS-server under your domain-name, you have

- Detect IP of old nameserver, let it be `a.b.c.d`
- Replace in xone-file of your domain old NS-RR `@ IN NS ns1.somehosting.com.` by new `@ IN NS ns1.superexample.com.`
- Edit SOA-record in your domain and replace `ns1.somehosting.com.` by `ns1.superexample.com.`
- Add new IN A records in zone for new host ns1 in domain `ns1 IN A a.b.c.d`
- Inform registrar about changing of authoritative DNS-server and provide for glue-record FQDN of new server **and it's IP** (because nobody will be able to get IP of host in your zone /ns1/ before accessing zone-data)